# win2D CanvasControl DrawImage() throughs the error "Value Does Not Fall Within the expected Range"?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

What i have Tried ?
XAML Code:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="grid">
<canvas:CanvasControl Draw="CanvasControl_Draw" CreateResources="CanvasControl_CreateResourcesAsync" ></canvas:CanvasControl>
    </Canvas>
```

C# Code:

```
CanvasBitmap canvasBitmap;
private async void CanvasControl_CreateResourcesAsync(CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
{
  canvasBitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, @"Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png");
  sender.Invalidate();
}
private void  CanvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
   Vector2 Vector = new Vector2();
   Vector.X = 10;
   Vector.Y = 10;
   args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(canvasBitmap,Vector);          
}
```

While using Canvas,the CanvasControl won't fire the Draw Event and if i use Grid instead of Canvas ,it fire the Draw event of CanvasControl. I need Canvas in the Background .And the Error "The Value does Not Fall Within The Expected Range " also occurs.Can Any one help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While using Canvas,the CanvasControl won't fire the Draw Event

Canvas is a control that uses absolute positioning. `CanvasControl` will not render without explicitly setting the `Width` or `Height`, and naturally will not trigger the `Draw` event.

If you want to trigger the `Draw` event, please set the Width and Height properties of `CanvasControl`, such as:

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="grid">
    <canvas:CanvasControl Draw="CanvasControl_Draw" 
                          CreateResources="CanvasControl_CreateResources"
                          Width="500" Height="500"
                          />
</Canvas>
```

> The Error "The Value does Not Fall Within The Expected Range " also occurs.

In simple terms, the reason for this error is that the `Draw` method is ready to render images that have not yet been loaded.

If you want to handle asynchronous methods in the `CreateResources` event, such as image loading, you can consider doing this:

```cs
CanvasBitmap canvasBitmap;
private void CanvasControl_CreateResources(CanvasControl sender, Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
{
    args.TrackAsyncAction(CreateResourceAsync(sender).AsAsyncAction());
    sender.Invalidate();
}

private async Task CreateResourceAsync(CanvasControl sender)
{
    canvasBitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, @"Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png");
}
```

This ensures that the `Draw` event will not be triggered before the `CreateResources` event ends.

Thanks.

Comment: is it possible to set the width and height of image drawned in win2d?if possible ,how to do?

Comment: The `DrawingSession.DrawImage()` method has many overloads, one of which you can limit the size of the picture through `args.DrawingSession.DrawImage (canvasBitmap, Vector, new Rect (0, 0, 200, 200))`;

Comment: it just crop the image to the mentioned width and height...i want full image ?

Comment: Hi, The `Rect` set in `DrawImage` is used to limit the rendering area. If you want the picture to be displayed in its entirety, you need to modify the resolution of the picture, you can use `CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, @"your_url", 200)`, add a parameter to limit the resolution of the picture.

Comment: its working fine now .I want to call the CreateResources Event whenever CanvasControl is Invalidate?The CanvasControl createResources event wont be called when canvasControl is Invalidate?